# Append returning false

Tags: prolog

I have the following rule in prolog where each constant in the formula (a constant is defined as c(a)) is added to a list of constants however, my append statement continually returns false.

```
getCONSTs( tt, []).
getCONSTs( ff, []).
getCONSTs( c(C), [C]).
getCONSTs( and(Q1, Q2), ListConstants) :-
   append(getCONSTs(Q1,A1),getCONSTs(Q2,A2),L1).
```

In the above append statement, if I give the rule a query such as:

```
?- getCONSTs(and(c(A),c(B)),[]).
```

The append statement should make a list of the constants: `[A,B]`

Comment: Prolog *predicates* are not *functions*, so they do not return values as you may think. Thus, `getCONSTs(Q1, A1)` does not return a value. It succeeds or fails if called. In the context of `append(getCONSTs(Q1,A1),getCONSTs(Q2,A2),L1).` it isn't called but merely passed as a term, which is not a list in this case, so it fails.

Answer (score 0):

What you here aim to do is calling `append/3` with as first two parameters terms with functor `getCONSTs/2`, so these are *not* lists. Sure there exists a predicate with the same name, but note that even if Prolog would *call* the predicate, it could only retrurn `true` or `false` (or raise an error, or get stuck in an infinite loop). But even calling the predicate is not happening: you construct a term, and it is more "coincidence" that there exists a predicate with the same name.

In Prolog one passes values by *unifying* variables with values, and then calling another predicate with that variable, like:

```
getCONSTs(and(Q1, Q2), L) :-
    getCONSTs(Q1, A1),
    getCONSTs(Q2, A2),
    append(A1, A2, L).
```

Note that a call with:

```
?- getCONSTs(and(c(A),c(B)), []).
false.
```

still results in `false`, since here you basically query if "*Is getConsts of `and(c(A), c(B))` equal to `[]`?*". In order to generate a list, you should again use a variable, like:

```
?- getCONSTs(and(c(A),c(B)), L).
L = [A, B].
```